# Pass an integer value to TikZ in LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I want to draw a rectangle with `\luacode`. For rectangle points, the coordinates values will be taken from code.

I try the following code. For rectangle, points are defined as `'(0,0) and (1,1)`. But i want to pass the `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` values into the `\tikzpicture` code. When i changed the related lines as `tp("\\draw [ultra thick] (xmin,ymin) rectangle (xmax,ymax);")`, the error gives that

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `xmin' (in 'xmin').
```

How to pass the values? Any suggestions are welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \luaexec{
    tp = tex.print
    local xmin = 0
    local xmax = 1
    local ymin = 0
    local ymax = 1
    tp(xmin.." "..xmax.." "..ymin.." "..ymax)
    tp("\\\\")
    tp("\\begin{center}")
    tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}")
    tp("\\draw [ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);")
    tp("\\end{tikzpicture}")
    tp("\\end{center}")
    }

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a different behavior between `\luadirect` & `\luaexec` commands and `luacode` & `luacode*` environments, please see page 2 in the [`luacode`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacode) manual. This is your example taking an advantage of knowing that.

```
%! lualatex mal-lua-to-tikz.tex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
tp = tex.print
local xmin = 0.5
local xmax = 3.5
local ymin = 0.5
local ymax = 1.5
local printme="The xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax are: "..xmin..", "..xmax..", "..ymin..", and "..ymax.."."
print("\n"..printme)
tp(printme)
tp("\\par\\medskip")
--tp("\\begin{center}")
tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}")
--tp("\\draw [ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);")% An old version...
tp("\\draw [ultra thick, draw] ("..xmin..","..ymin..") rectangle ("..xmax..","..ymax..");")
tp("\\end{tikzpicture}")
--tp("\\end{center}")
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]